# How to programmatically add a UITableViewController to a UINavigationViewController?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, tableview

I have

```
class SortViewController: UINavigationController{

 var myBtn: UIBarButtonItem?
 var tvc = UITableViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        myBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title:"Press Me", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "doStuff:")

        tvc.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = sortBtn
        self.pushViewController(tvc, animated: true)
        tvc.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

with all the necessary `override func tableView(...)` functions below.

This is all in a popover view that is called by a different view. While the popover opens, and myBtn appears properly on the navigation bar on top of the table, **the table does not populate as it should.** - that is, it does not populate at all.

Any ideas why?

**Note** everything in my app is completely programmatic; no storyboard whatsoever - this is intentional.

Thanks in advance,

Jona

Answer (score 0):

Assign `delegate` and `dataSource` property with self. Then only the methods of `tableViewController` will get called.

Comment: I don't understand. I've seen the delegate used before, but wen I try to do self.delegate (or tvc.delegate) it doesn't work: self.delegate gives the error "Type UITableViewController does not conform to protocol UINavigationControllerDelegate" - even when I add this delegate to the class. could you expand, please?